# Liquibase generates dropdefault change set when nothing has changed

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I am trying to generate liquibase  changeset programtically using liquibase and liquibase-hiberante using the code below

```
    Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/sample_database", "root", "");

    connection.getMetaData().getDriverName();
    Database database = new MariaDBDatabase();
    database.setConnection(new JdbcConnection(connection));
    final Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase("", new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);

    Database hibernateDatabase = new HibernateSpringPackageDatabase();
    hibernateDatabase.setDefaultSchemaName("sample_database");
    hibernateDatabase.setDefaultCatalogName("sample_database");
    hibernateDatabase.setConnection(new JdbcConnection(new HibernateConnection("hibernate:spring:" + "com.example.hibernateddl" + "?dialect=" + MariaDBDialect.class.getName(), new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor())));
    ObjectChangeFilter objectChangeFilter = null;
    String diffChangeLogFile = "/tmp/abc.xml";
    File outFile = new File(diffChangeLogFile);
    //    liquibase.update(changesToApply, new Contexts(contexts), new LabelExpression(labels));

    final Liquibase liquibaseUpdate = new Liquibase(outFile.toString(), new FileSystemResourceAccessor(File.listRoots()), database);



    try {
        DiffOutputControl diffOutputControl = new DiffOutputControl(false, false, true, null);
        diffOutputControl.setObjectChangeFilter(objectChangeFilter);
        CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog(outFile.toString(), hibernateDatabase, database, diffOutputControl,
                objectChangeFilter, StringUtil.trimToNull(null),null);


        liquibaseUpdate.update("");

    } catch (IOException | ParserConfigurationException e) {
        throw new LiquibaseException(e);
    }
```

My Entity looks like this

```
@Entity
public class Sample {
    @Id
    long id;
    @Column(name = "username",columnDefinition = "varchar(15) default 'dfds'")

    String username;
    @Column(name = "password",columnDefinition = "varchar(15) default null")
    String password;


    String oneMoreField2;

    String oneMoreField3;
}
```

when program is run first time the changeset is generated correctly and looks like this

```
 <createTable tableName="Sample">
            <column name="id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="SamplePK"/>
            </column>
            <column name="oneMoreField2" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
            <column name="oneMoreField3" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
            <column name="password" type="VARCHAR(15)"/>
            <column defaultValue="dfds" name="username" type="VARCHAR(15)"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```

when i run the same program second time i expect no changeset to be generated but my changelog file is modified to this

```
<changeSet author="ArshidDar (generated)" id="1627654919339-1">
        <createTable tableName="Sample">
            <column name="id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="SamplePK"/>
            </column>
            <column name="oneMoreField2" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
            <column name="oneMoreField3" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
            <column name="password" type="VARCHAR(15)"/>
            <column defaultValue="dfds" name="username" type="VARCHAR(15)"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="ArshidDar (generated)" id="1627655078245-1">
        <dropDefaultValue columnDataType="varchar(255)" columnName="oneMoreField2" tableName="Sample"/>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="ArshidDar (generated)" id="1627655078245-2">
        <dropDefaultValue columnDataType="varchar(255)" columnName="oneMoreField3" tableName="Sample"/>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="ArshidDar (generated)" id="1627655078245-3">
        <addDefaultValue columnDataType="varchar(15)" columnName="password" defaultValue="null" tableName="Sample"/>
    </changeSet>
```

can someone help?

Comment: It sounds like an issue with Liquibase not correctly reading database vs. hibernate metadata and/or not smoothing over particular differences.

If you run a `liquibase diff` between them, what does it list as the differences?  That will help us know what information Liquibase is working from as it figures out what changes need to be made.

Comment: had the same issue with liquibase-hibernate6:4.19.0. Seems to be fixed in 4.22.0